# Excel 2007 Pivot Tables Custom calculation?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot

Again I'm wrestling with Excel 2007! I have some data I'm using to generate a Pivot Table and I'd like to divide all of the data by 1000...

I know I could go in and change the original data by hand but I'd much rather have a formula in the Pivot table itself that does this for me.

Any thoughts?

ps: You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Create your pivot table, then in the Pivot Table options select Formulas/Insert Calculated Field.  Assuming your data field is named MonthlySum then the formulat would be =MonthlySum/1000.  Change the name of the Calculated Field as desired.  The newly named calculated field will now be available to add to the values in your Pivot Table.  As a side note you cannot use calculated fields as row labels.